# What is the separator used by Docker Compose for container names, dash "-" or underscore "_"?

Tags: docker-compose

pymediawikidocker automatically generates docker images and containers for mediawiki to get a "one-click" experience to setup a whole cluster of mediawikis using different versions / extensions and database settings for testing.

To be able to control the process the library https://github.com/gabrieldemarmiesse/python-on-whales is used which handles the docker compose commands.

The controlling python software now needs to work with the automatically generated containers and tries to calculate the name as docker compose does.

I get mixed results which might depend on operating system and Docker Compose versions, e.g. `mw1_35_8-mw-1` or `mw_135_8_mw_1`

According to https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6035 I tried:

```py
separator="-" if platform.system()=="Darwin" else "_"
```

but that still doesn't get consistent results and my CI tests in https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pymediawikidocker keep failing.

I am working around the problem now by trying out both but would love to know what the rules are for creating the container name.

Here is an example `docker-compose.yml` I am generating:

```yaml
version: "3"

# 2 services
#   db - database
#   mw - mediawiki
services:

#  MySQL compatible relational database
  db:
# use original image
    image: mariadb:10.9
    
    restart: always
    
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wiki
      MYSQL_USER: wikiuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "BOqdADGJYADBsZK7fg"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "hnOZz1xbkvySSh3RJg"
    
    ports:
      - 9308:3306
    
    volumes:
       - etc:/etc
      
# mediawiki
  mw:
    #image: mediawiki:1.35.8
    # use the Dockerfile in this directory
    build: .
       
    restart: always
    
    ports:
      - 9082:80
    
    links:
      - db
      
    depends_on:
      - db
    
    volumes:
      - wikiimages:/var/www/html/images
    # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
    # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
    # the mediawiki service
    # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
    
volumes:
  etc:
    driver: local
  wikiimages:
    driver: local%
```

Comment: Does it matter? If you need a specific container name, e.g. for `docker exec`, you can provide one: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name.

Comment: It's a compatibility problem - the library has been out there for a while already. For compatibility i would then have to use the more frequent choice which seems to be "-" by now. But i am not sure.

Comment: What's the _specific problem_ - why does the container name matter, do your end users care about it (in which case it probably shouldn't have been autogenerated to start with) or is it just an issue in CI, what _does_ happen in CI?

Comment: Thanks for asking for the motivation of my question. I am just curious what caused the inconsistency in the docker development process and what decisions there have been in the past to be able to decide whether i have to do anything or can stick with my guessing solution.

Comment: Most of that is questions SO can't really answer, you'd have to talk to the contributors to Docker Compose about how and why the generated container names are as they are. I'd guess if they aren't stable they aren't considered part of the public API and therefore shouldn't have been relied on to begin with.